# How to send API response through body with node.js?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, api

So I have an API that works fine and responds as I need, but I was wondering how I would set the response from the API to be in the `body`?

Right now it's just setting the response to be in a `<pre>` tag on the actual website (if I inspect element it shows like below):

```
<body><pre>{api response}</pre></body
```

but the only way I can access it is if it's in the `body` response.

If I check the `console.log` one the response, it just shows a bunch of blank spaces, so I was wondering how I would set up the API so it will respond in the body? Any help would be appreciated.

For the API I'm using `Node.js` with express and request packages if that helps at all

Comment: "respond in the body" ... what body? the web page? surely what the web page does with the response has nothing to do with the server

Comment: Please share some code. Also try using some command line tools like `curl` or `httpie` and provide the response from your server (what you see in browser inspector may not be actual response).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i understand your question, but i'm sure that you can insert your response in any place you want. Try using jade or mustache (handlebars).

Answer (score 0):

Here is [the example from the Express website](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html):

> ```
> app.get('/', function (req, res) {
>   res.send('Hello World!')
> })
> ```

This sends "Hello World!" in the HTTP response body.

So to send the API result instead you need to:

- Set the appropriate content-type header
- Send the result of getting stuff from the API

Such:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  var api_response = get_data_from_api();
  res.set('Content-Type', 'application/xml'); // or application/json or whatever
  res.send(api_response);
})
```